# How to group the Drop down Item List C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

In my asp.net MVC web application, I created a model like,

```
[Key]
public int ID {
  get;
  set;
}

[Required]
public string AccountName {
  get;
  set;
}

public string Description {
  get;
  set;
}

public int ? CurrentAccountID {
  get;
  set;
}
```

So from the controller, I'm binding the data to the ViewBag like,

```
ViewBag.CurrentAccountID = new SelectList(db.Accounts.Where(x => x.Status == true && x.CompanyID == CompanyID), "ID", "AccountName");
```

This is a sample of data now stored in the data table.

[image]

But in the view, I want to show the list in the dropdown list grouping by,

**Income**

Bank

Credit Card

**Expenses**

Office Expenses

Other Expenses

So the method is I want to group and show MainAccountID-wise data in the dropdown list.

Would appreciate it if anyone guide me on how to do it

This is the html view

```
<div class="col-sm-8"> 
    @Html.DropDownList("CurrentAccountID", null, "--Select Account Type--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-select acctype", @Id = "AccountTypes", @required = true, oninvalid = "this.setCustomValidity('Please Select the Account Type')", oninput = "this.setCustomValidity('')", })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is to include a navigation property to the parent account:

```
public virtual Account ParentAccount { get; set; }
```

Then include the parent accounts, and group by the parent `AccountName`:

```
var accountsGrouped = db.Accounts
    .Include(x => x.ParentAccount) // Include parent accounts
    .Where(x => x.Status == true && x.CompanyID == CompanyID)
    .OrderBy(x => x.ParentAccount.AccountName)
    .GroupBy(x => x.ParentAccount.AccountName) // Group by parent account name
    .ToList();

ViewBag.AccountsGrouped = accountsGrouped;
```

Then you'll have to manually create the select element and the `option` and [`optgroup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) elements:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <select id="AccountTypes" name="CurrentAccountID" class="form-select acctype" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Select the Account Type')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
        <option value="">--Select Account Type--</option>
        @foreach (var group in ViewBag.AccountsGrouped)
        {
            <optgroup label="@group.Key"> <!-- group.Key is the parent AccountName -->
                @foreach (var item in group)
                {
                    <option value="@item.ID">@item.AccountName</option>
                }
            </optgroup>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code., Perfectly works on the controller, and then data is sent to the HTML view, I'm getting an error called '' 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Key''' Any idea about this? I have debugged the code, when debugging in the view bag list it contain the data for the ``Key`` . But in the for each loop it returns an error

Comment: That is due to the fact that the ViewBag is a dynamic type, and the Razor view engine can't determine the type at compile time. Try to cast by replacing the `foreach` with `@foreach (var group in (IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Account>>)ViewBag.AccountsGrouped)`.